# Fitting exact equations using statsmodels and patsy

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting, statsmodels, patsy

Statsmodels allows the use of R-style formulas for equation fitting using patsy and `statsmodels.formula.api`. I would like to fit a specific function using columns in a pandas DataFrame, however, I can only seem to get close. For example, if I have the following dataframe with columns `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` and want to fit an equation of the form:

```
y = (A + B) / D
```

I can write the formula string as `y ~ (A + B):D-1` which results in two coefficients: `A:D and B:D`. I can then do some algebra and get rid of the coefficient in front of one of them, but not both.

Is there a simple way to fit a custom function of this form, without switching to scipy curve_fit or lmfit?

### Edits

To clarify, my goal is to obtain a fit value for D, letting A and B be values stored in the dataframe. To get this to work, I generated a dummy column of 1's called `D`. So the known values I have are `y, A, and B`, with `D` being my fit parameter. As of now, I obtain two a result that looks like `y=A:D*A + B:D*B`, which I can then extract to get something like `y=(A + B:D/A:D*B)/A:D.` This works well, except that I would to not have the coefficient in front of B.

Comment: What do you mean by "the coefficient in front of one of them"?  In your particular example, there can't be a unique solution, since you could, e.g., multiply all of A, B, and D by two (or any nonzero constant) and get an equivalent expression.  Also, it's not clear what you want to "fit", since your equation doesn't seem to leave any "room" for coefficients; you're just doing algebra directly on the data columns.

Comment: Note `:` in patsy and R specifies interaction terms not division. Can you clarify where/what the parameters are? If you have a explanatory variable `x = (A + B) / D`, then you can just create a new variable or column with pandas. If it's a nonlinear function in parameters, then lmfit, or curve_fit are currently the better choices than statsmodels.

Comment: Edited for clarification @BrenBarn . Maybe curve_fit would be a better choice here.

Comment: @DavidHagan: As user333700 mentioned, you can just create an `A_plus_B` column and then fit against that.

Comment: @BrenBarn Ahh. I see what you're saying. Yea, for this example that would definitely work. It might get messy as the equation becomes more complicated though. Thanks!